# Tag Map for CrossValidated

Tags: discussion, tags, site-promotion, data-visualization

I've just made a map of tags for **CrossValidated**.

In short: tag size is related to tag popularity and edges are related to tag co-occurrences in questions (or more precisely: the observed/expected ratio, see [Is there a term for $P(A\cap B)/[P(A)P(B)]$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40977/is-there-a-term-for-pa-cap-b-papb)).

For me it looks as a "snapshot" of topics and scope of this SE site. So if you want to you it in any way to promote Stats.SE - feel free!

Also, if you have comments how to improve its usefulness or niceness to our community, I would appreciate them (but bear in mind that I have no color esthetics).

[image: Tag Map for Stats.SE]

### Links:

- [An entry for StackExchange vis competition at Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow/prospector#211) (please vote if you like it :), it ends on Nov 3)
- [Recipe, code and images at GitHub](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange) (e.g. tweak the plot to your taste; feel invited to co-develop)

Comment: Nice example, what do the colors symbolize?

Comment: @AndyW Different communities, as detected by http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Modularity with Resolution=1.0.

Comment: Nice! For myself, I'm so happy to see how you all have adopted and supported the `[machine-learning]` community on here. It's now one of your largest tags! But seriously, this is *super cool* I'm sharing it with the team.

Comment: @Aarthi Nice to hear it! :) And congratulations for the [tag:machine-learning] community building.

Comment: This is fantastic! Nicely done!

Comment: I agree with Kyle. Great work !

Comment: I expected R and regression tags to belong to the same group.

Comment: Hi Piotr, would you be interested in disseminating this info on the blog? I know it is a little late to help voting, but this would be wonderful material to talk alittle bit more about. Feel free to stop by the [Skewed Distribution](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/549/skewed-distribution) chat room if you are interested.

Comment: @AndyW Thanks for suggestion and invitation! Yeah, for the competition is a bit late, but anyway, it seems to be a nice idea (I'm planing to work on the tag graph stuff, as I have a few more ideas).

Comment: That [tag:homework] tag is awfully conspicuous =P

Comment: @PiotrMigdal. Nice work. Do you intend to update this in the future (maybe when it complete 1 year old?)? That would be nice. Thanks

Comment: @AndreSilva Very likely. But this time I will try to do it interactive.

Comment: @AndreSilva The interactive, and up to date, version is there: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/new-interesting-page-tagoverflow.

Comment: Wonderful work! Congratulations and thank you.